# Calculating proportion

Tags: mean, proportion, weighted-mean, geometric-mean

I have a dataset of 10 people who share the cost of a service at the end of each month. The cost of the service is constant. Is there a fair way to split the cost of the service such that the difference between the maximum and minimum amounts paid is not too large?

This is the dataset that I am referring to:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: How about you use the numbers as weights to split the final cost?

Comment: That makes the difference between max value and min value relatively large.

Comment: What is "relatively large"?

Comment: Everyone could pay the same making the difference $0$.  But perhaps you do not want that either

Comment: @user2974951 Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough at first. Users who use the service more, expect to have a smaller difference with those who use it infrequently. This difference should be less than the case when weights are used.

Comment: @Henry I was looking for a way between your suggestion and when the weights are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the only fair way is to do it proportional to the number of users. Any attempt to make the difference smaller will be unfair. Derf's answer gives you a relatively simple way to let you pick a degree of unfairness to suit your sense of "too large".

Comment: I'm so glad you mentioned that. Maybe "fair" wasn't necessary in this case. People who use the service more, expect to be considered a benefit because they help the service remain stable during the month. Of course, they shouldn't pay less than those who use the service rarely. This is why I would like to reduce the difference between maximum and minimum values. Otherwise, the fair way is to use proportions as you mentioned. I followed the Derf method using the 50% split and got a reasonable result.

Comment: @MamadFasih What is fair to you may not be fair to these users. If I am one of those users and I am using this service a lot, which keeps it stable, I might complain that I should pay less because of this, and I might challenge your 50-50 split in favor of my cost. Likewise if I was a user who was using your service only occasionally I might complain that I should pay less since I am not using the service a lot and might also challenge your 50-50 split in favor of my cost.

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, that's right. Then do I need to look for a completely different method?

Comment: @MamadFasih no, what Peter wrote is pretty much the answer, using the numbers in the table as weights is the only "fair" way of splitting the cost, any other split will be subjective and arbitrary and might get challenged by the users. If you do end up using any other method you better be able to defend that position, why you chose a particular split.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you so much for your answer. It was very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Split the final cost first into two portions A and B (up to you whether 50:50 or like 70:30). Split A uniformly to the number of users then split B using the weights of the users.

For example, the final cost was 100 dollars . You split 70 dollars uniformly on the users. Then split 30 dollars on the users based on the weight. How you do the initial split for A and B determines how small the difference of the maxima and minima. Another example below using a 90% and 10% split.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Seems reasonable and transparent. I'm going to try that and see how it works.